# Why am I getting recursion when trying to implement trait for all reference types

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and having trouble implementing traits. Let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way. I'm trying to setup a trait with two functions for accessing a value. The get_value seems to function properly but when trying to setup the set_value with the &mut self reference, I'm getting the following error

```
warning: function cannot return without recursing
 --> src\main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: bool) {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot return without recursing
8 |         (*self).set_value(new_value);
  |         ---------------------------- recursive call site
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unconditional_recursion)]` on by default
  = help: a `loop` may express intention better if this is on purpose

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

Example code:

```
trait Trait1 {
    fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: bool);
    fn get_value(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<'a, T> Trait1 for &'a T where T: Trait1 {
    fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: bool) {
        (*self).set_value(new_value);
    }
    fn get_value(&self) -> bool {
        (*self).get_value()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Trait1 for &'a mut T where T: Trait1 {
    fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: bool) {
        (**self).set_value(new_value)
    }    
    fn get_value(&self) -> bool {
        (**self).get_value()
    }
}

struct Foo {
    value: bool
}

impl Trait1 for Foo {
    fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: bool) {
        self.value = new_value;
    }
    fn get_value(&self) -> bool {
        self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    
}
```

Comment: You don't need to implement trait `Trait1` for `& Foo` if not necessary. The `& Foo` would automatically call `Deref` trait to deref and get `Foo`. Finally, it get the implementation on `Foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the recursion error, because you only deref `self` once, turning it into a `&T` -- the type you're currently trying to implement the trait for -- while you want to get at a `T`. You don't get that error if you deref it twice like you do in the impl for `&mut T`.

You'll get another error, though, namely that that implementation won't work. You can't just deref a shared reference and then borrow a mutable reference from the referent. `*self` is a `&T`. You can't get a `&mut T` from that no matter how much you deref it.